# Multiset only verifying with one element array

Tags: verification, multiset, dafny

I'm having a problem with verifying if the count of an element in a multiset is a specific number. Below are two programs, one working (verifying correctly) and one not.

Verifies correctly:

```
method Main() {
  var a: array<int> := new int[1];
  a[0] := 2;
  assert a[0] == 2;

  var ms: multiset<int> := multiset(a[..]);
  print ms;
  assert ms[2] == 1;
}
```

Doesn't verify correctly:

```
method Main() {
  var a: array<int> := new int[2];
  a[0] := 2;
  a[1] := 3;
  assert a[0] == 2;
  assert a[1] == 3;

  var ms: multiset<int> := multiset(a[..]);
  print ms;
  assert ms[2] == 1;
}
```

Although, using a sequence directly seems to work just fine:

```
method Main() {
  var s := [2, 3];
  var ms: multiset<int> := multiset(s);
  print ms;
  assert ms[2] == 1;
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. For the first program `print ms;` prints out `multiset{2}` and in the second program `print ms;` prints out `multiset{2, 3}` which both seem fine, but Dafny raises an assertion violation for the second one at `assert ms[2] == 1;`. It seems that this happens when the arrays length is > 1.

Am I misunderstanding how multisets work, or is there something else going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

The second program verifies if you add `assert a[..] == [2, 3];` some time after setting `a[0]` and `a[1]`. For example, the following works:

```
method Main() {
  var a: array<int> := new int[2];
  a[0] := 2;
  a[1] := 3;
  assert a[0] == 2;
  assert a[1] == 3;

  var ms: multiset<int> := multiset(a[..]);
  assert a[..] == [2, 3];
  print ms;
  assert ms[2] == 1;
}
```

I don't know why that assert is necessary.

## Solution 2

There's another solution which doesn't require asserting the concrete value of `a[..]`. One can define a function `to_seq(a, i)` which explicitly computes the value of `a[i..]` and then `assert a[..] == to_seq(a, 0)`. In more detail:

```
function to_seq<T>(a: array<T>, i: int) : (res: seq<T>)
requires 0 <= i <= a.Length
ensures res == a[i..]
reads a
decreases a.Length-i
{
  if i == a.Length
  then []
  else [a[i]] + to_seq(a, i + 1)
}

method Main() {
  var a: array<int> := new int[2];
  a[0] := 2;
  a[1] := 3;

  var ms: multiset<int> := multiset(a[..]);
  assert a[..] == to_seq(a, 0);
  assert ms[2] == 1;
}
```

I'm again not really sure why that assert helps.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work, although is there a way to assert `a[..] = ...` for any `a`? It seems like there isn't which wouldn't be to useful since you would need to know the contents of `a` for this program to verify

Comment: You could assert `forall i : int :: 0 <= i < a.Length ==> a[..][i] == a[i]`, but that doesn't seem to help in your example. I don't know anything about the internals of Dafny, so I couldn't tell you why certain assertions help.

Comment: @LukaKerr I added another solution that (I think) asserts what you want: `assert a[..] == to_seq(a, 0);`. You could even wrap that assertion in a lemma if you want.

Comment: Thanks! Your second solution does indeed do what I wanted